# How to get the checkbox value in angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have been searching the threads here but can't really find the answer.

I am trying to get the value for the checked boxes when user check them in Angular. I have something like

```
<div class="checkbox">

<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="product in products">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="product"/> {{product.name}}
</div>

<button ng-click='add()'></button>
```

I want to have something in my js like

```
$scope.add = function() {
    //I want to add the checked product in the selectedProduct array
    $scope.selectedProduct = ['product1', 'product2', 'product4']  => the selected products.
}
```

How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: are you specifically asking how to do this with just Angular? or is just a jQuery solution

Comment: @ScottSelby i need the angular solution.

Comment: I'd recommend you use this: http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angular solution can be seen here: http://plnkr.co/edit/j63po37JBvc3bFdNAl3T

It's basically sending the event on ng-change

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="product in products">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="product.selected" ng-change="add(product)"/> {{product.name}}<br>
</div>
```

and I'm considering your controller to be like this:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.products = [
    {'name':'product1', 'selected': false},
    {'name':'product2', 'selected': false},
    {'name':'product4', 'selected': false}
  ];
  $scope.selected_products = [];

  $scope.add = function(prod){
    var index = $scope.selected_products.indexOf(prod.name);
    if(index == -1 && prod.selected){
      $scope.selected_products.push(prod.name);
    } else if (!prod.selected && index != -1){
      $scope.selected_products.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
})
```

So, you have a list of product objects that have a name and the selected state, you use the checkbox to keep the selected state there, and when you mark/unmark it, the ng-change event is triggered, passing to the add function in the scope the product, you then check the product.name index on the selected_products array, if it's not there, you add it, if it is already there, remove it. This way selected_products matches the selected checkboxes.

Comment: @BenLesh Thanks! IE8 is completely out of my field of vision, thankfully.

Answer (score 2):

Use ng-model="product.selected" in your HTML

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="product in products">
  <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="product.selected"/> {{product.name}}</label>
</div>
```

In your add function, you don't need to keep `selectedProducts` on your `$scope` unless you want to display it in your view somewhere, or possibly $watch it for some reason...

I'd recommend just building that array and using it within the closure of your add() function whenever you need it.

JS (for all browsers)

```
$scope.add = function(){
  var selectedProducts = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.products, function(product) {
    if(product.selected) selectedProducts.push(product);
  });

  // TODO: do something with selectedProducts here
};
```

JS using Array.prototype.filter (if IE8 isn't an issue)

```
$scope.add = function(){
  var selectedProducts = $scope.products.filter(function(product) {
    return product.selected;
  });

  // TODO: do something with selectedProducts.
};
```